# [error]Script failed with error: Error: Unable to locate executable file: 'powershell'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-postgres-database

**Functionality**: **Copy Data to Azure PostgreSQL Server through CI/CD Pipelines**

I have the SQL Script file of local PostgreSQL DB in the Azure DevOps Repository:
[image]

Using Classic Editor, I have added few tasks. From that the 1st task in Script Initialize from the working directory. That task is failing in finding the SQL Script Location:

**Get Sources**:

[image: Get Sources]

[image]

**CopyData**:
[image]

I come to know that Linux based agents allows only .ps1 or .sh files. I want to initialize the SQL script. not sure how to do that.

Could anyone please help me?